# How to rollback redux state and database if action request failed

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redux, sequelize.js

I have a submit button will dispatch one Redux action with three axios requests. The first one is `create a class`, the second one is `add a class teacher` and the last one is `add class students`. The teacher table has `classId` foreign key which is rely on the return value of creating class. And students has foreign key of `teachId` referring to teacher table.

When I click the submit button, in the button onClick action, it will dispatch the Redux action. How can I handle and rollback the Redux state and database if any of the request failed?

With the frondend, my code is like

```
export const finalizeClassSetting = ({ className, teacherName, StudentsDetail }) => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({ type: CLASS_REQUEST })
    try {
        //create new class
        resultClass = createClass(className)
        dispatch({ type: CREATE_CLASS, payload: resultClass })
        const classId = resultClass.classId
        try {
            dispatch({ type: TEACHER_REQUEST })
            resultTeacher = createTeacher(teacherName,classId)
            dispatch({ type: CREATE_TEACHER, payload: resultTeacher})
            const teacherId = resultTeacher.teacherId
            try {
                dispatch({type:STUDENT_REQUEST})
                resultStudent = createStudents(classId, teacherId, studentsDetail)
                dispatch({ type: CREATE_STUDENT, payload:resultStudent })
            } catch (error) {
                dispatch({ type: STUDENT_REQUEST_FAIL, payload: error })
            }
        } catch (error) {
            dispatch({ type: TEACHER_REQUEST_FAIL, payload: error})
        }
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({ type: CLASS_REQUEST_FAIL, payload: error})
    }
}
```

And `createClass`,`createTeacher` and `createStudents` will call the backend controller to create a new class, a new teacher and new students seperate. It's using Sequlize. It will be like

```
exports.createXXX = async (req, res) => {
    ...
    try {
        const resourceFound = await Model.findOne({
            where: { condition }
        })
        if (resourceFound) {
            return res.status(400).send({ status: 1, data: { message: "resource has existing" } })
        }
        const newResource = await Model.create({ xxxx })
        return res.status(200).send({ status: 0, data: { newResource: newResource, message: "create new resource successful" } })
        ...
    }
    catch(error) {
        return res.status(500).send({ status: 1, data: { message: "server error"}})
    }
}
```

With my current code above, if there is any error from request, the database saved to the database already cannot roll back.